# Nestjs: calling service functions from Model / Entity with sequelize hooks

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

In NestJS, I have to use a module service into an `entity/model` to populate data into `elastic-search` index. populating elastic search index logic is written in `Job.service.ts`.

I want to call that `onCreate` method from `Job.service.ts` from sequelize hooks present in models.

Here is code for `Job.ts` model/entity -

```
import { Table, Model, Column, AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table({ schema: "job", tableName: "job" })
export class Job extends Model<Job> {
  @AutoIncrement
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  id: number;

  @Column
  title: string;

  @AfterCreate
  static async jobAfterCreate(instance, options) {
    // <--- need to call job service onCreate method here
  }

  @AfterUpdate
  static async jobAfterUpdate() {}

  @AfterDestroy
  static async jobAfterDestroy() {}
}
```

and here is code for `Job.service.ts` -

```
//imports not added
@Injectable()
export class JobService {
  constructor(
    @Inject("SEQUELIZE")
    private readonly sequelizeInstance: Sequelize,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => ElasticsearchService))
    private readonly elasticsearchService: ElasticsearchService,
    @InjectModel(Job)
    private jobModel: typeof Job
  ) {}

  // here will write logic for updating elastic search index
  async onCreate(instance, options){
    console.log("ON CREATE INSTANCE:", instance);
    console.log("ON CREATE OPTIONS:", options);
  }
  async onDestroy(instance, options){
    console.log("ON DESTROY INSTANCE:", instance);
    console.log("ON DESTROY OPTIONS:", options);
  }
}
```

I tried injecting service into `Job` model but it did not worked.
And I cannot write elastic search logic inside model directly because for that I need `ElasticsearchService`.

Comment: For months I had to resolve to manually fire events and other actions and totally skip the model hooks but now I have found the answer. I have posted hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

## The Solution is To Override the provider

The primary way to inject information into the models is by overriding the injection behavior.

First, you would need to add a static property referencing the service in your model.

I am going to use the event emitter as an example here.

### Your Model Class

```js
import {Model, Table, Column, AfterCreate} from "sequelize-typescript"; 
import { EventEmitter2 } from "@nestjs/event-emitter";

@Table()
export class SomeModel extends <SomeModel> {

  // this would be your referencing
  public static EventEmitter: EventEmitter2;

  @Column
  public someColumn: string;


  @AfterCreate
  public static triggerSomeEvent(instance: SomeModel) {
    SomeModel.EventEmitter.emit('YourEvent', instance);
  } 
}
```

### The module where you are going to use the model

Now we are overriding the default injection process.

```js
import { EntitiesMetadataStorage } from '@nestjs/sequelize/dist/entities-metadata.storage';
import {
  getConnectionToken,
  getModelToken,
  SequelizeModule,
} from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { EventEmitter2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';

// The provider override
const modelInjector: Provider = {
  provide: getModelToken(AccountabilityPartnerModel, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME),
  useFactory: (connection: Sequelize, eventEmitter: EventEmitter2) => {
    SomeModel.EventEmitter = eventEmitter;
    if (!connection.repositoryMode) {
      return SomeModel;
    }
    return connection.getRepository(SomeModelas any);
  },
  inject: [getConnectionToken(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME), EventEmitter2],
};

// Updating the meta information of sequelize-typescript package to handle connection injection in to the model overridden.

EntitiesMetadataStorage.addEntitiesByConnection(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME, [
  SomeModel,
]);


// our custom module being used rather than the Sequelize.forFeature([SomeModel])
const someModelModule: DynamicModule = {
  module: SequelizeModule,
  providers: [modelInjector],
  exports: [modelInjector],
};


@Module({
  imports: [someModelModule],
  providers: [SomeService],
})
export class SomeModule {
}
```

Inject your model into your service as you would do using Sequlize.forFeature and InjectModel indicated as below.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
 constructor(@InjectModel(SomeModel) someModel: typeof SomeModel) {}

 public someFunction(data: any) {
   this.someModel.EventEmitter.emit('YourEvent', data);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will definitely try it out. looks like we need to customize things.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to documentation about such injections? You code does not work so I need to understands a concept at least.

Comment: I have a running sample in the following nestjs template I use frequently. https://github.com/maxgaurav/nestjs-framework-template

Comment: Its not very well documented on how to extend the nestjs sequelize package. What I did is that I read the actual code base found out how they did the injection for the @InjectModel decorator and override the provider token value with my values as written in the above answer. The DI then took care of the rest

Comment: Thank you for working sample )

@see
https://github.com/maxgaurav/nestjs-framework-template/blob/master/src/databases/model-bootstrap/model-bootstrap.module.ts